# Containing graphics in a container?

Tags: apache-flex, coordinates, ellipse

Hi I'm using flex and drawing a circle using the Spark Ellipse primitive.  I am setting the x,y coordinates of the circle myself.  I am drawing them within a TitleWindow component.  Is it possible to force the circle to not be allowed if I specify a coordinate that is outside the TitleWindow? Or do I have to check the coordinates manually myself?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check the coordinates manually yourself.